# Make text file with inconsistent structure into JSON object with inconsistent number of items

Tags: python, json

I have a file structure this way with hundreds of lines of data:

```
RHSA-2019:1797 CVE-2017-17485,CVE-2018-12022,CVE-2018-12023,CVE-2018-14718,CVE-2018-14719,CVE-2018-19360,CVE-2018-19361,CVE-2018-19362 cpe:/a:redhat:jboss_bpms:6.4
```

The only consistencies in the data is the space between the 3 fields i want to separate and the commas for the data that's in the middle. The number of items for the first data type labeled RHSA is always one, the data labeled CVE varies from 1 to 20 items  as well as the data labeled CPE.

I have tried to split the strings up using split() but im sure this can be done in one step with python as the data set is inconsistent in number of items but not structure.

I split the data by space using

```
data = rh.split()
for temp in data:
    print(temp)
```

so now I have

```
RHSA-2019:1797 

CVE-2017-17485,CVE-2018-12022,CVE-2018-12023,CVE-2018-14718,CVE-201814719,CVE-2018-19360,CVE-2018-19361,CVE-2018-19362 


cpe:/a:redhat:jboss_bpms:6.4
```

where each data set is on a separate line so ideally i would like to loop every 3 lines and throw the data inso a json like below:

```
[{"RHSA":{ "RHSA-2019:1797},
 {"CVE" :{ "CVE-2017-17485",
           "CVE-2018-12022",
           "CVE-2018-12023",
           "CVE-2018-14718",
           "CVE-2018-14719",
           "CVE-2018-19360",
           "CVE-2018-19361",
           "CVE-2018-19362" },
 {"CPE" :{ "cpe:/a:redhat:jboss_bpms:6.4"}]
```

Comment: As StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, please edit the code you have written to try solve this poblem into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you provided in example isn't valid JSON, but this script produces something similar:

```
line = 'RHSA-2019:1797 CVE-2017-17485,CVE-2018-12022,CVE-2018-12023,CVE-2018-14718,CVE-2018-14719,CVE-2018-19360,CVE-2018-19361,CVE-2018-19362 cpe:/a:redhat:jboss_bpms:6.4'

import re
from collections import defaultdict
import json

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in line.split():
    d[re.findall(r'^(\w+)', i)[0].upper()].extend(i.split(','))

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "RHSA": [
        "RHSA-2019:1797"
    ],
    "CVE": [
        "CVE-2017-17485",
        "CVE-2018-12022",
        "CVE-2018-12023",
        "CVE-2018-14718",
        "CVE-2018-14719",
        "CVE-2018-19360",
        "CVE-2018-19361",
        "CVE-2018-19362"
    ],
    "CPE": [
        "cpe:/a:redhat:jboss_bpms:6.4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have a link to any documentation to see how this works to gain a better understanding?

Comment: @JohnMonte Official documentation for `defaultdict` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict and `re` module https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html is good start